# What is Atomic transaction regarding databases and how do I impliment it in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, atomic

I have two tables in question:

`Users` table which contains user's balance column(casino_bakiye)

2. `Xpgtransactions` table: Where I save transactions coming from the API.
   I also have a route /debit where debit requests are sent. In the request, there is amount and username among the data sent.

So what I am  to do

Get the user from the users table with the username that comes with the request
Get that user's balance

3. decrement that balance
4. return a response with that user's current balance.
5. save the transaction to the `Xpgtransactions` table

For example, if the current user's balance is 1000 , then the request comes with amount as 100, I am to decrement that 1000 by 100 and return the resulting amount in the response. Meaning that 1000 - 100 = 900 So I have to return 900, thats after decrementing that user's balance by 100. Then save the transaction amount to `xpgtransactions` table.

THE PROBLEM:

Now the problem is that with a few transactions, the decrement logic doesn't happen. It just but saves the transaction to the Xpgtransactions table. So I wonder how it skips decrementing the amount and saves the data to `xpgtransactions` table.

So in this case, if the current user amount is 1000 and the request comes with 100, I need to decrement 1000 by 100: 1000 - 100 = 900 now in this case it returns 1000 instead of 900, it skips decrementing logic. I tried Laravel transactions but the issue still persists.

So while asking this question in a Laravel forum, someone introduced an `atomic transaction` phrase and asked me to research it. But I can't find any source explaining it precisely and more so how to apply it in my case. Could someone explain it precisely?

My CODE:

```
public function Debit(){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $username = $data['Login'];
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    if(!$user){
        $rivalaoResponse = ["d"=>["ErrorCode"=>-10,
                                  "HasErrors"=>true,
                                  "Message"=>"InvalidPlayer"]];
        return response()->json($rivalaoResponse);
    }
    $type="debit";
    $userId = $user->id;
    $amount = $data['Amount'];
    $gameId = $data['GameId'];
    $roundId = $data['RoundId'];
    $sequence = $data['Sequence'];
      
    $game = XpgTransaction::where('gameId', $gameId)
                            ->where('roundId', $roundId)
                            ->where('sequence', $sequence)
                            ->first();

    DB::beginTransaction();
    
    try {
        if(!$game){
            $trxn = new XpgTransaction;
            $trxn->user_id = $userId;
            $trxn ->request=json_encode($data);
            $trxn->type =$type;
            $trxn->save();
            if($user->decrement('casino_bakiye', $amount)){
                $trxn->casino_balance = $user->refresh()->casino_bakiye;
                $trxn->save();

                DB::commit();
                $currentBalance = $user->refresh()->casino_bakiye;
                $rivalaoResponse = ["d"=>["Data"=>[(float)$currentBalance],
                                        "ErrorCode"=>0,
                                        "HasErrors"=>false,
                                        "Message"=>""]];
                return  response()->json($rivalaoResponse); 
            }else{
                $currentBalance = $user->refresh()->casino_bakiye;
                $rivalaoResponse = ["d"=>["Data"=>
                                            [(float)$currentBalance],
                                            "ErrorCode"=>-1,
                                            "HasErrors"=>true,
                                            "Message"=>"Unknown error"]
                                    ];
                return  response()->json($rivalaoResponse);
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }else{
            $rivalaoResponse = ["d"=>["ErrorCode"=>-21,
                                    "HasErrors"=>true,
                                    "Message"=>"Duplicate transaction"]
                                ];
            return response()->json($rivalaoResponse);
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $currentBalance = $user->refresh()->casino_bakiye;
        $rivalaoResponse = ["d"=>["Data"=>[(float)$currentBalance], 
                                            "ErrorCode"=>-1,
                                            "HasErrors"=>true,
                                            "Message"=>"Unknown error"]
                            ];
        return  response()->json($rivalaoResponse); 
        DB::rollBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Let me look at it @RiggsFolly

Comment: _Big Point_ NOTHING happens after a `return`. That passes control to the caller and no more of the function/method is executed So placing a Rollback after a `return` means the rollback wont happen

Comment: It is rolling back the transaction as it should be, but the API does not give provision for rolling back. The data from the request must decrement the balance and response returned on the current balance. That is where there is a problem because sometimes the decrement operation is skipt.